# EF 6 Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

```
[Table("Pages")]
public class Page
{
    [Key, Column("Page_Id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public Page()
    {
        this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }
}

   [Table("Categories")]
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public Category()
        {
            this.Pages = new HashSet<Page>();
        }
     } 
[Table("CategoryPages")]
    public class CategoryPage
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int category_ID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int page_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }   

public partial class Context : DbContext
{

    public Context() : base("name=Context") { }
    public virtual DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CategoryPage> CategoryPages { get; set; }
}
```

When try to access categories like below code (from method from repository)

```
   int Id = 1;
   Page page = context.Pages.Where(x => x.ID == Id).FirstOrDefault();
   Category category = page.Categories.FirstOrDefault();
   return category;
```

Gives me error

> {"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details."} Inner Exception : {"Invalid object name
>   'dbo.PageCategories'."}

I don't have table name dbo.PageCategories, I renamed dbo.PageCategories to dbo.Categories

Still it's searching for this table.

Comment: Your code does not contain any "PageCategories". This code cannot produce the error you pasted.

Comment: that's what my concern, I search PageCategories in entire solution gave me 0 result but it produce error like that.

Comment: Hi, could you *rebuild* the project that contains `[Table("CategoryPages")]` ? i believe, either that one, or the category one is renamed. Anyway, you could always peek into the binaries using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

Comment: I could able to build, i get error when i try to access that entity property runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code. I believe you have renamed the table after generating the database, which means the models and the database are out of sync. You have to add a new migration for that (or remove the existing one and add a new one), and then you should be able to update the database.

If you haven't worked with EF Code First Migrations, this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) should help.